# Add a few rows from one table to another according to criteria in the other table, and add a group code to each group

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I'm new to the field, so I'd love help.
I prefer answers that can be implemented in access or excel.

I have two tables, the first has information of specific trips, here is an example:
[example table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHMNi.png)

and the second has information of other trips here is an example:[example table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LILs.png)
,both of which have the following columns: 1. tripid, 2. time.

I want to copy all the trips from Table 2 that were made within an hour from the trips listed in Table 1,
And I want each group (trip in Table 1 and all of its continuation trips within an hour) to have a common code (in a new column named group code,where each group will have the same code).

Here's an example of how I want it to come out:[exsample result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFd0U.png)

Thank you

Comment: can you post the tables definitions or your idea of tables ?

Comment: Use VBA and CurrentDb.Execute to build and run an INSERT SELECT action SQL to add batch of records. What do you mean by 'new column'? Should NOT have process that routinely programmatically adds fields.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

As the "continuation code", just concatenate the tripid and time from table1.  So, this results in:

```
select t1.tripid, t1.time, t1.tripid & t1.time as group_code
from table1 as t1
union all
select t2.tripid, t2.time, 
       (select top 1 t1.tripid & t1.time
        from table1 as t1
        where t1.time <= t2.time and t1.time > dateadd("hour", -1, t2.time)
        order by t1.time desc
       ) as group_code
from table2 as t2
```

Comment: I tried and it didn't work, maybe because I did it in Access. I updated the question and attached pictures for illustration

Comment: @eli . . . This should work in MS Access, although you may need to convert `time` to a string for the concatenation to work.

Comment: Did you see the exsample result, regarding the group code

Comment: @eli . . . If you want any help, you have to describe what "doesn't work" means.  Is there an error?  Does it produce the wrong results?

Comment: this is the error: syntax error in query expression (select top (1) t1.tripid & t1.time from table1 as t1 where t1.time <= t2.time and t1.time > dateadd("hour", -1, t2.time) order by t1.time desc )